# If $\cot(x)=2$ and $\cot(y)=3$ show that $x+y=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cot(x)=2$ and $\cot(y)=3$ show that $x+y=\frac{\pi}{4}$.
I was trying to find x and y but is some weird thing. Also note that $x,y\:\in (0,\pi/2)$
Second idea was to write : $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=2$ and $\frac{\cos y}{\sin y}=3$ and adding this two I'll get $\frac{\cos(x+y)}{\cos x \cos y}=5$. Than what?

Comment: If it's not so difficult why can't you do it :)? On a serious note, give your question a better title that actually describes the content. Also, show what you tried, don't just say you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: using basic trigonometric identitites:$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\frac12+\frac13}{1-\frac12\frac13}=1\;\implies\;\ldots$$

Comment: Oooh, I am so stupid... thx , I get it how is done

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** We have $$\cot x=2\implies x=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)$$ and $$\cot y=3\implies y=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)$$ Now use the addition formula to show that $$\tan(x+y)=1$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Whoops. Forgot to remove that after the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Alt. hint: $\;x,y$ are the angles marked in red below.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a great answer, ***endorsed***; now I need to spend the time to figure it out.  Cheers!

Comment: This is a very nice hint, yet it'd be much better if it had at least some of the vertices in it marked with letters as the way it is it'd be very cumbersome to try to explain it... Further hint: the dotted triangle is a right isosceles one.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. Final hint would be that $x+y$ equals the [exterior angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem#High_school_exterior_angle_theorem) of the third vertex, which in turn equals the acute angle of the isosceles right triangle produced by the auxiliary construction.

Answer (score 2):

From [this wikipedia page on trigonmetric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities), we see that

$\tan(\alpha + \beta) = \dfrac{(\tan \alpha + \tan \beta)}{1 - (\tan \alpha)(\tan \beta)}; \tag 1$

with

$\cot x = 2, \; \cot y = 3, \tag 2$

we find

$\tan x= \dfrac{1}{2} = 2^{-1}, \; \tan y = \dfrac{1}{3} = 3^{-1}; \tag 3$

thus

$\tan(x + y) = \dfrac{2^{-1} + 3^{-1}}{1 - 2^{-1} \cdot 3^{-1}} = \dfrac{5 \cdot 6^{-1}}{1 - 6^{-1}} = \dfrac{5 \cdot 6^{-1}}{5 \cdot 6^{-1}} = 1; \tag 4$

with $x, y \in (0, \pi / 2)$, we have $x + y \in (0, \pi)$; the only value 
of $x + y$ in this range satisfying (4) is

$x + y = \dfrac{\pi}{4}. \tag 5$